# How to render action as HTML and invoke ActionFilters from another controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

From within a controller action I need to call another action and have any applicable `ActionFilter` on the called action fired as well. I need to do this because I am passing the resultant HTML to a PDF generator.

This is what I currently have, but it doesn't call `SomeActionFilter.OnActionExecuting()`

```
[SomeActionFilter]
public class FooController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult ActionOne()
     {
          return View();
     }

     public ActionResult ActionTwo()
     {
         // This is how I'm rendering the view to HTML at the moment
         var controllerDescriptor = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(ControllerContext.Controller.GetType());
         var actionDescriptor = controllerDescriptor.FindAction(ControllerContext, "ActionOne");
         var result = actionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext, new Dictionary<string, object>()) as ViewResult;

         ViewEngineResult viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, null);

         var builder = new StringBuilder();
         using (var writer = new StringWriter(builder))
         {
             var context = new ViewContext(controllerContext, viewEngineResult.View, result.ViewData, result.TempData, writer);
             viewEngineResult.View.Render(context, writer);
         }

         string actionOneAsHtml = builder.ToString();
         // From here on I'm just using the rendered HTML to generate the PDF ... 

         byte[] pdf = _acrobatExportService.ExportFromUrl(new AcrobatExportModel
         {
             Html = actionOneAsHtml 
         });

         return File(pdf, "application/pdf", "export.pdf");
     }
}
```

I know I *could* call the action using HTTP, but that seems redundant.

Comment: Assuming the second action returns a PDF stream, what would the first action return to the caller? A ViewResult? If so what do you want to do with this PDF?

Comment: Essentially ActionOne() returns a ViewResult and ActionTwo() returns the same HTML (with a few minor style changes) as a PDF